# Passing array type to Google Data Studio

Tags: google-apps-script, graphql, looker-studio

I am currently making a connector to google data studio.

I want to obtain a field from a production graphql endpoint called "questions". The hard part is that this field is an array of string ids, e.g. ['id-1','id-2','id-3'].

```
  var questions= fields.newDimension()
   .setId('questions')
   .setName('Questions')
   .setType(types.TEXT)
   .setDescription('question')
```

It appears that google data studio does not accept schema types of an array. My constraint is mainly that I cannot write a new resolver for my graphql and I just want to deal with the existing state of my graphql server without making changes.

#### Question

1. How do I pass this array string to google data studio? Is there an existing type I can use?
2. If 1) does not work, can I make a graphql query that counts the length of an array value? (since this is what I want essentially)

#### Some Links

[Data Studio Reference of Types](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/semantics)

Cheers.

Comment: This needs to be handled in the `getData()` function of the connector. Your code points to `getSchema()` and subsequently, `getFields()` part of it. I too [recently created a connector](https://script.gs/create-a-google-data-studio-community-connector-with-key-auth-type/) and had to accordingly create helper functions to transform source API responses to required "rows" for Data Studio to consume. Can help figure this out, as required :)